# How do I enable php error log on Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, nginx, logging, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel Homestead to develop a laravel 5.2 site.

It's working fine, but recently I started getting the utterly useless Laravel / nginx `502 Bad Gateway` error, which could mean anything from a php error to a server misconfiguration.

I'm looking in the homestead box's `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` and php error logging is active and is set to log to `error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log`

This log file is empty however, and I can't find any info on how to enable basic PHP error logging.

The basic laravel log at `storage/logs/laravel.log` is getting written to but it has no information on these 502 errors.

From `/var/log/nginx/myapp.log` file:

```
2017/03/21 17:50:42 [error] 5239#0: *12 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: replication-interface.app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "myapp.app"
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon

Comment: Did you somehow managed to activate the PHP logging?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-enable-nginx-access-log-on-laravel-homestead